# How do I make gmock treat all warnings/failures as errors?

Tags: c++, compilation, googlemock

I have some test code written using gmock. Due to some code changes, the test is not executing completely, and completes prematurely (I know this, as I can see failure messages in the logs saying expected to execute once, but did not run for many functions). However, the compilation/execution is not failing, as it getting an exception that it is expecting (as the same exception is thrown in multiple places). So the test appears to pass, but it is not executing completely. How can I make gmock treat all warnings/failures as errors?

Comment: Show sample code, please.

Comment: @Jarod42 Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*(<function name>))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active

This is the error I am getting in the logs

Comment: It's a regression issue, so it was working fine earlier, due to some other code changes this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true
```

in the method where the tests were failing helped catch these failures while running the tests. The `throw_on_failure` flag causes GMock to throw an exception when a mock related exception fails.

[Reference](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=m0RBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT489&lpg=PT489&dq=throw_on_failure%20gmock&source=bl&ots=GXovN9hXNu&sig=ACfU3U0pWwgINgDP9YUm-5HPerpgL8ncWw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIjtey7J3mAhUSbisKHXSqC20Q6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=throw_on_failure%20gmock&f=false)